# How do I profile a Maven Application in Netbeans?

Tags: maven-2, netbeans, profiling, profiler

I've got a project using Maven 2 as the build tool.  Now I am using Netbeans 6 as my IDE and really want to be able to use the profiler.  Is there any way I can  get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this might be more complicated. It wasn't. To use the Netbeans profiler with your Maven 2 project you simply need to add a single pair of parameters when running your java app. Call up the project's Properties dialogue, select the "Run" tab and add something like the following to the jvm args:

```
-agentpath:"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.0\profiler2\lib\deployed\jdk15\windows\profilerinterface.dll=\"C:\\\"Program Files\"\\\"NetBeans 6.0\"\\profiler2\\lib\\"",5140
```

This meant that now when I ran my app (F6) execution would wait for me to attach the profiler. Cue real time graphy goodness. Sweet.

Comment: Just an update - profiling of a maven project has been working out-of-the-box since NetBeans 6.5.